# Simple Python code not working but not throwing an error in the editor

Tags: python

I started learning Python from CodeAcademy, and I realized right away that the course was outdated. I continued the course with VisualStudio open in case I wanted to make sure something didn't change. However, I tried making a very simple program that outputs the date in VisualStudio and it's not doing anything.

```
from datetime import datetime
now = datetime.now
print(now.second)
```

When I run this in the VisualStudio environment, it throws the error:

```
AttributeError: 'builtin_function_or_method' object has no attribute 'second'
```

When only seconds ago I had done it in CodeAcademy. I have done my fair share of googling and found nobody who has come across the same issue.

Comment: You need to *call* the method `datetime.now` by adding parentheses. `now = datetime.now()`

Comment: Useful shortcut: Paste your code, highlight it, hit Ctrl+k. No need to manually put spaces or backticks.

Comment: You can refer to the official python document to see the latest usage of each module.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`now` is a function (technically a class method) so call it like this: `print(now().second)`

Comment: Can always count on Stackoverflow to make me sound stupid